# SVG paths stroke not crisp

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG which is an artistic rendition of Bob Dylan. It has a big viewbox `viewBox="0 0 2000 2000"` and it is the `background-image` for an element with a a `background-size` of 400 x 400 in the browser.

It looks the way I want except in firefox, the edges of the hands are blurry (paths with id of "hand1" and "hand2"). I added `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to those paths and it made no difference. Is there anything else I could consider/change?

I will remove the stroke if I can't find a solution for all browsers but it makes his hands look kinda chubby!

Screenshots below and source file is available [here](https://gist.github.com/robole/6bbc2e99d839f19d00446108491df7e9).

chrome:
[image: chrome screenshot]

firefox:
[image: firefox]

Comment: removing crispEdges improves things a lot for me. Chrome and Firefox look pretty similar with that change.

Comment: You could also try `style="stroke-width:1px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

Comment: Removing crispEdges and setting the stroke-width to 3 produces a decent result imho

Comment: removing `crispEdges` helped. i was using the svg for an animation and in the CSS I had `perspective:100px;` on the svg element, which was distorting things in firefox. removing these sorted it 100%. thanks